# Function to compare tables

Tags: matlab

How can I compare different tables, for example (table1 & table2 & table3), and then create a new table containing specific columns from table 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Please provide more information on your issue. Such things as what you have tried, what has worked and what has not worked along with any scripts and/or error messages. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, if you want more specific answers you'll have to ask more specific questions. Having said that, here is as best as I can help:

[The Matlab documentation for tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) will tell you almost anything you'd like to know. You might want to look at the functions [`stack`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.stack.html), [`join`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.join.html) and/or [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.union.html) in particular, as I believe that might be what you've after in terms of merging different tables together. Remember that wet you combine different columns from tables, you're implying the entires to be identical across the rows. Make sure your data is constructed such that this is indeed true.

To ask some basic questions of the table all you really have to do is to pick a column (which you'll get as a cell array) and do your test on it. Repeat for the other table and compare. Here is an example of making two random tables and then doing some kind of comparison of the two.

```
close all; clear; clc; % Clear workspace
%% Make random data
% Random name of length n
randl = @(n) randsample('a':'z',n,true);
randu = @(n) randsample('A':'Z',n,true);
randname = @(n) [randu(1) randl(randi(5)) ' ' randu(1) randl(randi(5))];

% Random social secutity number
randintchar = @(n) randsample('0':'9',n,true);
randssn = @() [randintchar(3) '-' randintchar(2) '-' randintchar(4)];

% Random blood pressure
randbloodpress = @() randi(28,1,2)+[100 50];

% Random favourite icecream flavour
flavours = {'vanilla','chocolate','strawberry','rum raisin'};
randfav = @() cell2mat(randsample(flavours,1));

% Helper to repeat a function N times
rep = @(fun,N) arrayfun(fun,zeros(N,1),'UniformOutput',false);

% Random data table
varnames = {...
    'name','social_security_number',...
    'blood_pressure','favourite_ice_cream'};
randtable = @(N) table(...
    rep(@(x)randname(5),N),rep(@(x)randssn(),N),...
    cell2mat(rep(@(x)randbloodpress(),N)),rep(@(x)randfav(),N),...
    'VariableNames',varnames);

%% Make random table1 and table2
table1 = randtable(100);
table1.Properties.Description = 'Data 1';
table2 = randtable(89);
table2.Properties.Description = 'Data 2';

%% Compare properties of tables
% Check the descritions
t12_samedescript = strcmp(...
    table1.Properties.Description,...
    table2.Properties.Description);

% Check both tables have the same first column
t12_varnames1same = strcmp(...
    table1.Properties.VariableNames{1},...
    table2.Properties.VariableNames{1});

%% Ask some questions of a table 
% All those who's name starts with 'O'
t1_startswitho = cellfun(...
    @(x)strcmpi(x(1),'o'),...
    table1.name);

% All those who like rum and raisin
t1_likesrnr = cellfun(...
    @(x)strcmpi(x,'rum raisin'),...
    table1.favourite_ice_cream);
t2_likesrnr = cellfun(...
    @(x)strcmpi(x,'rum raisin'),...
    table2.favourite_ice_cream);

% Number of those in table 1 whos name starts
% with 'o' *and* who like rum and raisin
t1_nboth = sum(t1_startswitho & t1_likesrnr);

% Compare which dataset has more rum and raisin lovers
t1_fraction_likesrnr = sum(t1_likesrnr)./size(table1,1);
t2_fraction_likesrnr = sum(t2_likesrnr)./size(table2,1);
t1_better = (t1_fraction_likesrnr > t2_fraction_likesrnr);
```

Working with tables can be a bit messy, as they're designed to be very general and work with mixed datatypes.